# DatePicker in DataGrid hidden until you double-click on it

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datepicker

I am using .NET 3.5, WPF.

I embedded Datapicker in the Data Grid. Changing the date in Data Picker correctly triggers the event RowEditingEnd of DataGrid. However, the column with DataPicker shows no content until you double-click on the cell. After double-clicking the cell, DatePicker shows up. Is there any way to make DatePicker permanently visible?

The xml of DataGrid:

```
    <WPFToolkit:DataGrid Name="dgCustomPermPopup" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="30,20,35,60" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="False" RowEditEnding="ch" >
        <WPFToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <WPFToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="50" />
            <WPFToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding Path=DisplayDate}" Width="40" />
            <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DisplayDate">
                <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WPFToolkit:DatePicker Text="" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DisplayDate}" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"  SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </WPFToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </WPFToolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Maybe this would help you [Single Click for edit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing&ProjectName=wpf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CellTemplate instead of CellEditingTemplate to make it visible always. CellEditingTemplate is the template that is used to display the contents of a cell that is in editing mode.

```
 <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WPFToolkit:DatePicker Text="" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DisplayDate}" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"  SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
                        </DataTemplate>
   </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: When using CellTemplate, chaning the date in data grid will not trigger RowEditingEnd event in datagrid

Comment: ok. For what you are using RowEditEnding event ? Can you do whatever you are doing in this event in the setter of the DisplayDate property ?

Answer (score 0):

What about a combined solution?

```
<WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WPFToolkit:TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayDate}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WPFToolkit:DatePicker Text="" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DisplayDate}" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"  SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
    </DataTemplate>
</WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```